# WebRTC Play Audio Input as Microphone

Tags: input, audio-streaming, webrtc, microphone

I want to play my audio file as microphone input (without sending my live voice but my audio file) to the WebRTC connected user. Can anybody tell me how could it be done?

I have done some following tries in the JS code, like:

### 1. base64 Audio

```
<script>
var base64string = "T2dnUwACAAAAAAA..";
var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + base64string);
snd.play();
var Sound = (function () {
var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
return function Sound(src) {
    var snd = new Audio(src);
    df.appendChild(snd); 
    snd.addEventListener('ended', function () {df.removeChild(snd);});
    snd.play();
    return snd;
}
}());

var snd = Sound("data:audio/wav;base64," + base64string);
</script>
```

### 2. AudioBuffer

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var isPlaying = false;
var sourceNode = null;
var theBuffer = null;

window.onload = function() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "sounds/DEMO_positive_resp.wav", true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = function() {
  audioContext.decodeAudioData( request.response, function(buffer) { 
        theBuffer = buffer;
    } );
}
request.send();
}

function togglePlayback() {
        var now = audioContext.currentTime;

        if (isPlaying) {
            //stop playing and return
            sourceNode.stop( now );
            sourceNode = null;
            analyser = null;
            isPlaying = false;
            if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
                window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame;
            //window.cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
            return "start";
        }

        sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        sourceNode.buffer = theBuffer;
        sourceNode.loop = true;

        analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyser.fftSize = 2048;
        sourceNode.connect( analyser );
        analyser.connect( audioContext.destination );
        sourceNode.start( now );
        isPlaying = true;
        isLiveInput = true;
        return "stop";
    }
```

Please help me out in this case. It would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Here is a demo that may help you stream mp3 or wav using chrome:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/stream-mp3-live.html

#### Here is, how it is written:

- http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/getting-started/#stream-mp3-live

#### And source code of the demo:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/demos/stream-mp3-live.html
- https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/222

#### Use in 3rd party WebRTC applications

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var context = new AudioContext();
var gainNode = context.createGain();
gainNode.connect(context.destination);

// don't play for self
gainNode.gain.value = 0;

document.querySelector('input[type=file]').onchange = function() {
    this.disabled = true;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(e) {
        // Import callback function that provides PCM audio data decoded as an audio buffer
        context.decodeAudioData(e.target.result, function(buffer) {
            // Create the sound source
            var soundSource = context.createBufferSource();

            soundSource.buffer = buffer;
            soundSource.start(0, 0 / 1000);
            soundSource.connect(gainNode);

            var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
            soundSource.connect(destination);

            createPeerConnection(destination.stream);
        });
    });

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
};

function createPeerConnection(mp3Stream) {
    // you need to place 3rd party WebRTC code here
}
```

---

### Updated at: 5:55 PM - Thursday, August 28, 2014

Here is how to get mp3 from server:

```
function HTTP_GET(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert("Unexpected status code " + xhr.status + " for " + url);
            return false;
        }

        callback(xhr.response); // return array-buffer
    };
}

// invoke above "HTTP_GET" method
// to load mp3 as array-buffer

HTTP_GET('http://domain.com/file.mp3', function(array_buffer) {

    // Import callback function that provides PCM audio data decoded as an audio buffer
    context.decodeAudioData(array_buffer, function(buffer) {
        // Create the sound source
        var soundSource = context.createBufferSource();

        soundSource.buffer = buffer;
        soundSource.start(0, 0 / 1000);
        soundSource.connect(gainNode);

        var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        soundSource.connect(destination);

        createPeerConnection(destination.stream);
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear Muaz, I have tested my audio file with `RTCMultiConnection` and it is working pretty cool but only by passing an input as file that should be chosen from my computer. I want to pass my server files on that. To do it so, I had a try by choosing some predefined file into `<input type=file>` but it seems that it cannot be happen with it. 
Is there any way other than FileReader object to read a buffer?

Comment: Thanks a million bro :)
live Long

Comment: Ok, so here is another issue using Twilio (3rd Party) API. I am putting the same code you sent me is not working. I think I am missing something. do I need to connect RTCMultiConnection and Twilio.Device both? Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: RTCMultiConnection is a simple wrapper, so you don't need to use it. I don't know how Twilio API looks like, however above snippets should be working within any application/API that allows you pass "custom-streams" before creating peer connections.

Comment: No worries, I have integrated RTCMultiConnection with Twilio. but there is another issue, i.e. sound quality is passing really badly. Without Twilio, sound quality is fine. I don't know why it is. Is there any function or some per-requisites for sound-file to be like bitrate greater than 256 KBPS ?
Thanks !